# When I click select button after category button, why isn't the String being printed and null being printed instead?

Tags: java, class, user-interface, hierarchy

```
package simpleclass;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SimpleClass extends BaseClass {
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Category");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("Select");
    JFrame f = new JFrame();

    SimpleClass() {
        f.add(b1);
        f.add(b2);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        f.setSize(200, 200);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    new SubClass();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        });
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(astring);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleClass();
    }
}

class BaseClass {
    String astring;

    public void setString(String astring) {
        this.astring = astring;
    }
}

class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    SubClass() throws FileNotFoundException {
        super.setString("WHYnull");
    }
}
```

In this code there is one base class `BaseClass` and two subclasses `SimpleClass` and `SubClass`. There are two buttons. When the button *"Category"* is pressed, then the String *"astring"* is being set to "WHYnull". Now my question is that when I press *"Select"* button after that, why is *"null"* being printed? Isn't the variable *"astring"* exclusive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state:

> When the button "Category" is pressed, then the String "astring" is being set to "WHYnull".

Yep, this is correct, but it's only true for the `new SubClass()` that you've created (and discarded) in the first ActionListoner. It will have no effect on the aString that is a field of the original program, the current `this`.

My suggestion: this is not a problem that should be solved with inheritance. Leave inheritance completely out of this picture.

I'd do:

```
  b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // try {
        // new SubClass();
        // } catch (IOException ex) {
        //
        // }

        setString("Fubar");
     }
  });
```

Also note that your code should not have empty catch blocks as that's the Java equivalent of driving your car with your eyes closed. Exciting yes, but also very dangerous.

---

You asked about a GUI that uses multiple classes, a common example is a Model-View-Control or MVC type program design where the program's logic resides in the model, the GUI in the view, and the interactions between the two in the control. For example, taking your small program as an example, one could do something like:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class SimpleMCV {

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      final SimpleView simpleView = new SimpleView();
      final SimpleModel simpleModel = new SimpleModel("");
      MainControl mainControl = new MainControl();
      mainControl.setUp(simpleView, simpleModel);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple GUI");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(simpleView);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class SimpleView extends JPanel {
   private JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);

   public SimpleView() {
      textField.setFocusable(false);
      add(textField);
   }

   public void setTextFieldText(String text) {
      textField.setText(text);
   }

   public void addAction(Action action) {
      add(new JButton(action));
   }
}

class MainControl {
   public void setUp(final SimpleView simpleView, final SimpleModel simpleModel) {
      simpleView.addAction(new SimpleControl(simpleModel, "Fubar"));
      simpleView.addAction(new SimpleControl(simpleModel, "Snafu"));
      simpleView.addAction(new SimpleControl(simpleModel, "Bohica"));

      simpleModel.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            simpleView.setTextFieldText(simpleModel.getSomeText());
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class SimpleControl extends AbstractAction {
   private SimpleModel simpleModel;

   public SimpleControl(SimpleModel simpleModel, String name) {
      super(name);
      int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
      putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      this.simpleModel = simpleModel;
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      simpleModel.setSomeText(e.getActionCommand());
   }

}

class SimpleModel {
   private List<ChangeListener> listenerList = new ArrayList<>();
   private String someText;

   public SimpleModel(String someText) {
      this.someText = someText;
   }

   public String getSomeText() {
      return someText;
   }

   // change text and notify all listeners
   public void setSomeText(String someText) {
      this.someText = someText;
      for (ChangeListener changeListener : listenerList) {
         changeListener.stateChanged(new ChangeEvent(this));
      }
   }

   // allow outside classes to add a ChangeListener
   public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener cl) {
      listenerList.add(cl);
   }
}
```

Comment: @User: `"You mean in gui one can not deal with many classes?"` What? No, not true at all. Most of my GUI's use many classes, and your question has absolutely nothing to do with GUI. Instead you're using inheritance to solve a problem that isn't solved with inheritance, pure and simple.

Comment: Can you give an example or a link?

Comment: @User: an example of what?

Comment: An example in which there are different classes using 1 gui class @Hovercraft